# Why NetBeans is not happy with <s:radio> tag and marks it in red?

Tags: jsp, netbeans, struts2

I am using Struts2 `<s:radio>` today:

Following [Struts doc](https://struts.apache.org/docs/select.html), I have the following code in my jsp:

```
<s:radio name="outputFormat" label="Choose an output format" list="#{'01':'Biological Outcome Only','02':'Raw Binary Data Only','03':'Biological Outcome and Raw Binary Data'}" value='01' />
```

NetBeans is not happy with my code and marks the whole list component `list="#{'01':'Biological Outcome Only','02':'Raw Binary Data Only','03':'Biological Outcome and Raw Binary Data'}"` in red. But it allows me to run the program. The three radio buttons are displayed, but the first button is not pre-selected, as we want. In other words, `value='01'` is not working.

Now following [mkyong example](https://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-sradio-radio-button-example/), I change my code as follows:

```
<s:radio name="outputFormat" label="Choose an output format" list="#{'1':'Biological Outcome Only','2':'Raw Binary Data Only','3':'Biological Outcome and Raw Binary Data'}" value="1" />
```

This time, everything is working perfected: the three radio buttons are displayed and the first button is pre-selected. But even that, NetBeans is not happy either in that it marks the whole list component `list="#{'1':'Biological Outcome Only','2':'Raw Binary Data Only','3':'Biological Outcome and Raw Binary Data'}"` in red. Do you know why?

Comment: So what do you want to know? Why `value` isn't working? Or why netbeans is a... does that?

Comment: Roman, Thank you for your link and answer.